# jQuery find index of <p> NOT relative to parent not working for XML

Tags: jquery, xml

In my HTML, the 2nd `<p>` is active.

The Index relative to it's parent is `2`. Let's call it `global-Index`.

```
<div>
  <h1>TITLE (global-Index: 0; p-Index: N/A)</h1>
  <p class="">1st P (global-Index: 1; p-Index: 0)</p>
  <p class="active">2nd P (global-Index: 2; p-Index: 1)</p>
  <p class="">3rd P (global-Index: 3; p-Index: 2)</p>
</div>
```

My goal was to make it Index `1`. I wanted the position relative to all `<p>` Elements. Let's call it `p-Index`.

I could get the `p-Index` successfully in the DOM with an element that has a class.

PROBLEM: I can't get the `p-Index` with an XML element with an attribute.

```
 <DIV>
   <H1>TITLE (global-Index: 0; p-Index: N/A)</H1>
   <P active="0">1st P (global-Index: 1; p-Index: 0)</P>
   <P active="1">2nd P (global-Index: 2; p-Index: 1)</P>
   <P active="0">3rd P (global-Index: 3; p-Index: 2)</P>
 </DIV>
```

```js
/**
 * HTML section
 */

// Find Index of <p> with class="active"
var activeElement = $('div p.active');

var activeIndex = activeElement.index('p')// restricts the index only to 'p' elements.

console.log("HTML Element " + activeElement.prop("tagName") + " '" + activeElement.text() + "'" + ' has Index ' + activeIndex)



/**
 * XML section
 */

// Create XML
var xml = '<DIV><H1>TITLE (global-Index: 0; p-Index: N/A)</H1><P active="0">1st P (global-Index: 1; p-Index: 0)</P><P active="1">2nd P (global-Index: 2; p-Index: 1)</P><P active="0">3rd P (global-Index: 3; p-Index: 2)</P></DIV>';

// Parse XML
xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
  $xml = $(xmlDoc);

// Find Index of <P> with attribute active="1"
$($xml).each(function() {

  var activeElement = $(this).find('DIV P[active="1"]')

  var activeIndex = activeElement.index('P')// unlike in HTML,'P' does not work here!

  console.log("XML Element " + activeElement.prop("tagName") + " '" + activeElement.text() + "'" + ' has Index ' + activeIndex)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h1>TITLE (global-Index: 0; p-Index: N/A)</h1>
  <p class="">1st P (global-Index: 1; p-Index: 0)</p>
  <p class="active">2nd P (global-Index: 2; p-Index: 1)</p>
  <p class="">3rd P (global-Index: 3; p-Index: 2)</p>
</div>
```

In the XML section, the `'P'` selector on `index()` results in `-1`, meaning that no element was found.

*Omitting the selector gives me `global-Index` `2` which is correct, but not what I want.*

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drake7/k3fy0qvw/24/)

Comment: js fiddle code seems to be working fine so what's the issue here?

Comment: How can I achieve the same for XML as I did with HTML? My 2nd p should have index 1.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your approach.

First, in your html and xml you are not looking for the same things:

In your html you are looking for `'div p.active'`, meaning a `<p>` node, which is has a `class` attribute (the `.`), which attribute has an attribute value of `"active"`, all this inside a `<div>` node.

In your xml, on the other hand, you are looking for `DIV P[active="1"]`. This means you are looking for  a `<P>` node, which has has (the `[ ]`) an attribute called `active`, which attribute has an attribute value of `"1"`, all this inside a `<DIV>` node.

While the two look similar, they are definitely not and the use of "active" in both just adds to the confusion. In the html, "active" is an attribute value, while in the xml, it is the attribute name itself.

The second problem is how your index searches are formulated - that is, the array within which you are looking to index your target array member.

So try changing:

```
var activeElement = $('div p.active');
var activeIndex = activeElement.index('p')
```

to

```
var activeElement = $( "div p[class='active']" );
var activeIndex = $( "p[class]" ).index( activeElement )
```

and

```
 var activeElement = $(this).find('DIV P[active="1"]')
 var activeIndex = activeElement.index('P')
```

to

```
var activeElement = $( "DIV P[active='1']" );
var activeIndex = $( "P[active]").index( activeElement )
```

and they will both return `1`.

Edit:

I ran this in a browser this way:

```
$(document).each(function() {
var activeElement = $( "DIV P[active='1']" );
var activeIndex = $( "P[active]").index( activeElement )
  document.write("XML Element " + activeElement.prop("tagName") + " '" + activeElement.text() + "'" + ' has Index ' + activeIndex)
});
```

Output:

```
XML Element P 'bar' has Index 1
```

Comment: Thank's for the great explanation! However I still could not make it work for the `XML section`! First problem: If I omit `this`, `activeElement.prop("tagName")` is `undefined`. 2ndProblem: Whether I omit `this` or not, I still get `-1`

Comment: OK, thank's for the edit! `1)` Can you confirm that your code doesn't work in my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drake7/k3fy0qvw/24/) `2)` In your edit, how do you parse the XML? Could you provide your full test setup?

Comment: @drake7  Take a look at [the modified jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uqc1bgp3/2/).